# Not able to pass data between view controllers

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to pass the String `sendname` in `ViewController` to the String variable `finalName` in another view controller, `DatabaseTableViewController`. Here is my code in `ViewController`:

```
                    self.sendname = self.name.text!
                    let vc = DatabaseTableViewController()
                    print("sending: \(self.sendname)")
                    vc.finalName = self.sendname
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                    let next = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DatabaseTableViewController") as! DatabaseTableViewController
                    self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and my variable in `viewDidLoad` in `DatabaseTableViewController`:

```
class DatabaseTableViewController: UIViewController {

    var finalName: String? = nil
```

My code correctly prints `sending: Satya`, but when I print the value of `finalName` in `DatabaseTableViewController`, it still gives me `nil`. What should I do?

Thanks, Satya

Answer (score 0):

you assign the value to the instance that's not presented

```
                let vc = DatabaseTableViewController()
                print("sending: \(self.sendname)")
                vc.finalName = self.sendname
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                let next = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DatabaseTableViewController") as! DatabaseTableViewController
```

you preset `next` that you didn't assign data to

```
 self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

---

Note if your vc exists in storyboard then instantiate with

```
 let next = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DatabaseTableViewController") as! DatabaseTableViewController
```

if programmatically then use

```
 let vc = DatabaseTableViewController()
```

so try

```
    let vc= UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DatabaseTableViewController") as! DatabaseTableViewController
   print("sending: \(self.sendname)")
   vc.finalName = self.sendname
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you assign it to a view controller and then present it? In other words, what is the code for me to present vc?